# export ES6 class in Node 4.x Unexpected reserved word

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have the following in a Node scripts:

```
"use strict";

class Whatever {
    constructor() {
        console.log("I'm in the constructor!");
    }
}

export default Whatever;
```

I get `Unexpected reserved word` regarding `export`.

What am I missing here? How do you specify a class definition in an external file and include/require it?

Comment: I don't think ES6 modules are supported in Node by default, are you running this with the `--harmony`, `--harmony_modules` flag etc ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node.js doesn't support ES6 modules by default. You would need to activate them with the `--harmony` or `--harmony_modules` flag. Default ist the CommonJS declaration [(`require`/`module.exports`)](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Modify your code to support the CommonJS syntax:

```
"use strict";

class Whatever {
    constructor() {
        console.log("I'm in the constructor!");
    }
}

module.exports = Whatever;
```

Comment: As I said in the question, I'm using Node 4. Thanks

Comment: Ah, sorry :) Skipped that part then. Will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks I saw it supported ES6 classes and just assumed that is the proper way to export classes. Didn't realize you could use the old CommonJS syntax for classes still. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ES6 modules aren't stable in Node yet, but you can use `--harmony_modules` to enable them. This obviously is not recommended in a production environment.

[ES6 support in Node 4.x](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/)